How can I make VS Code also rename symbols in Python docstrings when refactoring?
I use VS Code in my Python projects, I currently use docstrings to document it. However, when I rename a symbol (F2), of a function parameter for example, it is not updated in the docstring. Do you know if it is possible to make the VS Code refactor consider the docstring? I know Pycharm can do this, so I would like to do the same in VS Code.
I tried using tools like autodocs, but even so, the docstrings are not seen by the refactor, they are just highlighted.

At least for Pylance (the most commonly used Python language support extension for VS Code), this is the subject of an active feature-request: Rename symbol also rename in docstrings #2938. I suggest that you give that issue ticket an upvote to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".
A maintainer Heejae Chang has replied there saying:

Once we complete our new Python docstring parser, we might be able to build on that to support this. However, since Python docstrings do not have an official method for referencing other Python symbols within the docstring, it will be, at best, optional and based on heuristics for us to determine how to match text in a Python docstring to an actual symbol.

As a temporary workaround, you can use find and replace. Or you can look for other Python language support extensions that do this.
